# Weird behavior for :first-child and :nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it just me, or is `:first-child` and `:nth-child` not working a logical way?

In case that it's just me, then please explain me how it works.

Here is 3 examples of the usage which I really don't understand:

My HTML is the following:

```
<div class="footer">
    <span class="a">a</span>
    <div class="b">b</div>
</div>
```

First example: (*which **does not** hide the `b`-class for some reason*)

```
body .b:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marktopper/7gapd4c4/0/)

Second example: (*which **does not** hide the `b`-class for some reason*)

```
body .b:nth-child(1) {
    display: none;
}
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marktopper/7gapd4c4/1/)

Third example: (*which **finally** hide the `b`-class for some reason*)

```
body .b:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marktopper/7gapd4c4/2/)

Does anyone have a logical explanation of this behavior?

Comment: First example: is `b` the first child among with parent container children? No, hence it's not hidden. In this case you need `.b:first-of-type`. Second and third: is `b` the first child? No, it's the second. Hence the result.

Comment: Thanks @dfsq, I saw those on [can i use](http://caniuse.com/) `:nth-of-type`, `:nth-last-of-type()`, `:first-of-type`, `:last-of-type`, `:only-of-type`. Which seems to be the one that I actually needs to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`first-child` and `nth-child(1)` mean the *first* **child** node.  The `span.a` is the first node.  It doesn't matter that you use a combinatorial selector.  `.b` is not a first child, so it is not selected.

In this case you could use `.b:first-of-type` because `div` and `span` are different types, but if they were both `span`s that wouldn't work.  Using an additional selector like `.b` won't help much with nth-child selectors except in cases like:

```
<div>
    <div class=b>b</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>not b</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class=b>b</div>
</div>
```

Then you may have a use for `.b:first-child`.

Comment: In add if you set `b:first-child` is just to be sure if the first node is `b` then apply the class....

Comment: Thanks @Explosion Pills. For others having those issues, I found the following selectors as well on [can i use](http://caniuse.com/) `:nth-of-type`, `:nth-last-of-type()`, `:first-of-type`, `:last-of-type`, `:only-of-type`.